# I want keep alive background service after kill process

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I created background enable messenger app using ionic.

Use by katzer background mode plugins.

But I want keep alive background service when I double press home button and slide up kill the app (IOS) or kill app using X button at task manager (ANDROID).

How can I know it action and solve the problem. I don't want kill the app.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

}, false);

document.addEventListener('pause', function() {

}, false);

document.addEventListener('resume', function() {

}, false);
```

Comment: When the user kills your app it should be killed. Therefor this is not possible on iOS and should never be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can't keep the app alive after kill, at least on iOS. But my feeling is you should respect your user, if she wants to kill an app, die with dignity :D

Answer (score 0):

Look into zombie and orphan processes. Zombie processes will continue to run and cannot be killed. Orphan processes are child processes whose parents have been killed, but are still running. Orphan processes can be killed. (You probably want zombie processes)

Answer (score 0):

I think my communication make misunderstand to everyone.

Anyway, I found this line

```
- (void)onAppWillTerminate
```

I just want do not execute logout() my messenger after double press home button and slide up like facebook or instagram.

I can't receive message if I do action it (double press home button, slide up). Because if I do that..disconnected from server after a little minutes.

Comment: This method may or may not be called when the app terminates.  When the user slides up from the app switcher it almost certainly won't be called. The correct way to keep an app "alive" on iOS is to us Pushkit notification. This will relaunch your app when the push is sent